# не могу импортировать модуль в питоне

Tags: python, pycharm

Установила модуль `request` с помощью `pip`, установилось успешно. пытаюсь импортировать модуль в `pycharm` (путем `import requests`), не получается, пишет , что модуль не известен  `import requests`

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests')

Comment: посмотрите в окружение `PyCharm` он установился `Settings -> Project -> Interpreter`

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1: Через виртуальное окружение
Обычно venv в директории вашего проекта
Откройте виртуальное окружение относящееся к этому проекту и уже там введите:
pip install requests

Вариант 2: установить через настройки pyCharm
Settings -> Project -> Interpreter -> +
В строке поиска введите нужную вам библиотеку (в вашем случае requests), выберете ее, и нажмите install package

Comment: Вариант 2 помог. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я такую ошибку ловила, когда модули устанавливались в одну папку, а интерпретатор работал из второй. Мне помогло удалить весь пайтон и пайчарм и накатить заново (плюс сделать шаги из "вариант 2" в [ответе выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/822660/17609))